# modeling spherical mirror in python using predefined function

Tags: python, opticalflow, optics-algorithm, optical-drive, haskell-optics

I want to use a spherical mirror in a python script for optics simulation, please is there a function in python can simulate the spherical mirror (concave or convex).

I try to introduce a additional phase to the beam but it's not working because of that the light reflected by the spherical mirror change the direction (converge or diverge).